# Can the GC have a performance impact when reading camera images?

Tags: c#, camera, garbage-collection

I do have a cammera appllication (C#, Windows WPF) which I run as standalone app and with the same code for the camera in a framework. Now I do see a huge performance impact when comparing those two applications.

The standalone app has a good framerate while the application with the framework is very, very slow. Than I compared the thread times for both:

- Standalone APP: 4 Threads; The camera thread is the longest one and calls two methods
- Framework APP: 21 Threads; The camera thread is the longest one and calls the same two methods with the same time allocation as the standalone application

Therefore I do not see any difference except the number of threads.

When checking the process memory in debug mode, I see this:

[image]

Here I can see that the GC comes every ~10s for the standalone application while in the framework app every ~1s.

Questions:

- Has the number of threads an impact on the camera performance when the camera thread for both application looks pretty much the same?
- Has the GC interruption time (~8ms) which comes every second an impact on the performance in respect to the framerate?

What could be solution? Is there another way to find the root cause?

Thanks

Comment: What does "in a framework" mean? What framework?

Comment: @Charlieface I use the same camera source code (camera interface) in another application, that's all

Answer (score 0):

> Has the number of threads an impact on the camera performance when the camera thread for both application looks pretty much the same?

The total number of threads has a very minimal impact. The important thing is how the threads are used. If you have a modest number of threads, i.e. a UI thread and a capture thread, I would not expect any significant difference between .net framework & .Net Core+

> Has the GC interruption time (~8ms) which comes every second an impact on the performance in respect to the framerate?

GC can absolutely affect performance, especially if you are doing frequent, large, short lived, allocations. I.e. allocating buffer space for each incoming frame. This is kind of the worst case scenario for GC, since the allocations end up on the Large Object Heap, and thus require gen 2 collections to be collected.

If you are capturing video I would suggest using some form of pooling for the frame buffers. See for example [MemoryPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=net-7.0).

However, I would probably suggest doing some more in-depth performance analysis. There are tools that should show the overall time spent blocked by the GC. You should also be able to see what threads are used, and what the threads are doing. [Visual studio have some tools builtin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2022), but there are also third party tools, some with trial offerings, that might be easier to use.

It does not really look like you are limited by the CPU, so it is likely your threads spend most of the time blocked by *something*, maybe the GC? maybe some lock? Maybe some IO-operation? It is not really possible to tell from the given information. My guess would be that you have made some simple mistake somewhere so you are not comparing apples to oranges, and just need to find where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comprehensive answer. When using a profiler to get more detail information about the timing of each thread I get following overall profile:

[image]

Here is the hotspot in the user code @ Thread#15 (yellow) within the function "ConvertTo" with 79.2%. When filtering the profile only to the user code I get this picture:

[image]

Here again, the "ConvertTo" function takes 90.4% followed by Thread#2 with only 8.1% and the "Dispose" of the image.

Now when comparing those two pictures with the standalone application (has the same source code for the camera) I get this:

[image]

The comparision shows more or less the same profile for me. The most time is used for "ConvertTo" and "Dispose", which is also the same code for both application. So I am currently wondering which part has an impact on the camera frame rate at the end?!

EDIT
The VS Projekt Prop. for both application are as follows:
[image]